# Unhandled FileNotFound Exception in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll While Trying to Read an Async OAuth Request Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http

**Update / Theory**
I believe this specific error would be better illustrated with the Newtonsoft.json 4.5.0.0 version, which doesn't seem to exist on their website: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/ or at all, really- has anybody else seen this?

**Original**

While trying to read a response after requesting an OAuth token (using the following code), I receive this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=34etz678bn443' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseURL + RequestOAuthTokenURL);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                    string.Format("{0}:{1}", Username, Password))));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

string urlParameters = "";
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
     var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<DataObject>>().Result; //<-- offending line
     foreach (var dataObj in dataObjects)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("{0}", dataObj.Name);
     }
}
```

I've read that this can be caused by a number of things (from bad request params to missing files in the dependency tree). However, I haven't been able to locate the root of the problem by hunting down any suggested answer. Also, my username & password look alright, and do not cause a 401 (entering garbage credentials do, and this error does not occur). Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a config/installation error... Did you check what version of NewtonSoft is on the target PC ?

Comment: No dice- everything seems to be correct :/

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem for me:
http://www.tomasvoracek.com/2015/07/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version4-5-0-0-cultureneutral-publickeytoken30ad4fe6b2a6aeed-or-one-of-its-dependencies/
I did a "get-package" in the Tools/NuGet Package Manager/Package Console Manager" and found the version to 6.0.4 and set the bindingRedirect version to 6.0.0.0 and that fixed the problem.

Comment: link is broken  ...